# onPlaybackStopped not being called Naudio

Tags: naudio

I am making a tone and an i put it into a WaveProviderbuffers and then I mix that tone with another file and I play that mix, however onPlaybackStopped not being called.

I have convert my WaveProviderbuffers to Waverstreams 
I  used that to make a WaveChannel32.
and I set PadWithZeroes = false, but the stop event is still not being called.

side note If i play a file without mixing in a WaveProviderbuffers, the stop event is called, so that does work.

What am I missing?

> WaveProviderToWaveStream wptws = new
>   WaveProviderToWaveStream(Sinebuffer, Sinebuffer.BufferLength);
>
> WaveChannel32 temp = new WaveChannel32(wptws);
>                   temp.PadWithZeroes = false;
>                   mixer.AddMixerInput(temp); mixer2 = new SampleToWaveProvider(mixer);  waveout.Init(mixer2);
>
> ```
> waveout.Play();
>        stopToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
>        puaseToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
>        playToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
> ```

the tone does stop playing at the time I set, but the stop event is still not being called

Answer (score 0):

You have a never ending waveprovider somewhere in your playback graph. It may be `BufferedWaveProvider` in this case. I'd also recommend not using `WaveChannel32` and `WaveMixerStream32` - use a `SampleChannel` and the `MixingSampleProvider` instead.